# Enable mobile data programmatically Android 8.0

Tags: android, adb

I tried the command in Android 6.0(non rooted device) using
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svc data enable");
But, didn't work,I have even set the app as device admin.

Comment: Google has removed/deprecated the support to enable/disable the mobile data programmtically.

Comment: But the same command works in Adb.Is there any special permission ?

Comment: It wont work on physical devices due to security issues that google doesnt provide users those permissions now. If you want to do so you can only if you hv a rooted device

Comment: @PrajwalW Alryt.Thanks

Comment: pls do upvote the comment